# country based product price should be changed in commerce kickstart?

Tags: commerce, location

I have installed [commerce kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart). I have to add the two prices for single product.

> If Indian subscribers view the site means product price should display as
>   2000 INR.
>
> If other users visit the site means product price should display as $ 50.

How to identify the user whether view the site in India and other country and how to change the price also ? Anyone guide to me? Based on country how can i change the price also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IP based Determination of country module](http://drupal.org/project/ip2country) for identify the user ip address and the country.

You can use [Commerce Multicurrency](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency) module for INR price field in the products content types.

By using Rules module to change the price for indian users

Comment: See my answer there https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/275805/14465 
for step by step implementation of this method (exept I used  the smart_ip module instead of ip2country  )

Answer (score 1):

[Commerce Multicurrency](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency) module can solve your issue.

This module enhances some of the multi-currency capabilities of Drupal Commerce.

> Current features:
>
> - UI for fine granular definition of exchange rates. (Every currency combination can be defined separately if needed)
> - Synchronization of currency exchange rates directly from the European Central Bank (ECB).
> - UI to specify which rates shall be synchronized and which are handled manually.
> - Generation of currency specific price fields inclusive generation of rule-set to handle them.
> - hooks for easy integration of custom currency exchange rate sources.

Comment: Thank u for your reply. how to change the currency based on user locations?

Comment: @Nandhana I think through this module you can change the currency based on user location.

Comment: Sure. Now i am trying. after that i will accept the answer

Comment: Ok sure @Nandhana

Comment: multicurrency not supported for geolocation