# How to convert currency dynamically on Product Page?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using drupal 7 and commerce modules. I want a dynamic currency converter on product display page or cart page (priority is product display page). Suppose Product A is displayed with price 1 USD and user is from India or some other country then I want to give the user an option to change the currency before adding product to cart. If the user selects INR then the 1 USD will be converted to INR which makes it 67 and payment will be made in INR. How can I achieve this kind of functionality in Drupal ?

Suggestions are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Please follow http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158322/country-based-product-price-should-be-changed-in-commerce-kickstart i guess this question is similar to the question asked in the link

Comment: Thank you Shilpa for replying. commerce_multicurrency was the solution.

Comment: So should i post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [Commerce Multicurrency](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency) module for INR price field in the products content types.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer there https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/275805/14465 for a step by step solution. It include a way to automaticaly change currency based on the user IP.